# cakephp $this->User->find('all');

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

Im totally new to cakephp and done some beginners tutorial and I see this line of code:

$this->User->find('all');

My question is this, where did 'User' come from since Ive never declared it on the program and I did not return an error but when I change the name of that, a bunch o errors happen.

Anyone pls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through the model documentation  here http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html  .
User is Model class in app/model folder.If you didnot created that ,cakephp will do it itself by default